# What is the good way to stop a query reader in a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, .net-4.7.2

I'm starting to work with [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) to try it out, and I'm wondering how can I stop a query which returns an [Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netframework-4.7.2) [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and that may take some time to execute.

I guess that I can't stop the query on the server, but what I'm specifically looking for is to stop the read of the [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2) which contains the result of this query.

Here's a code sample with my BackgroudnWorker and a sample query :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker worker;

    public Form1 (Point location)
    {
        this.Location = location;
        InitializeComponent();
        worker = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true,
        };
        worker.DoWork += this.Worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    #region Form
    private void ButtonBack_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (worker.IsBusy && !worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }
        this.Close();
    }

    private void TextBoxSearch_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (worker.IsBusy)
        {
            if (worker.IsBusy && !worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                worker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Worker
    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            if (worker.IsBusy && !worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                worker.CancelAsync();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            // Where I'd like to cut the IEnumerable if worker.CancellationPending to shorten time of process
            foreach (LigneHS ligne in GetLignesHS(worker.CancellationPending))
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }

                // Do work
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    #endregion

     // Sample query
    internal static IEnumerable<LigneHS> GetLignesHS (bool cancellationPending)
    {
        string requete = "SELECT * FROM [MY_TABLE] ORDER BY [date] DESC";
        SqlConnection conn = BDD.OpenBDD16();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(requete, conn);

        List<LigneHS> lignes = new List<LigneHS>();
        LigneHS ligne = new LigneHS();

        try
        {
            if (!cancellationPending)
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read() && !cancellationPending)
                {
                    ligne = new LigneHS();

                    if (reader["id"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        ligne.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);

                        // filtering null values for every column

                        lignes.add(ligne);

                        // tried to add the yield return here, but can't inside a try-catch
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetLignesHS : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            command.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return lignes;
    }
}
```

As it is here, cancellationPending of the query doesn't update if the worker is asked to stop.

I first thought of using a [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) return to interrupt the foreach if the BackgroundWorker is asked to stop. But, I'm using a try-catch in the treatment of the query, so I can't.

I know that using a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.7.2) as I did when I used straight thread will work, but I wonder if it is the best way to achieve what I want here.

Comment: Do you really want to waste your time with BGW, when you could use async/await Task?

Comment: Easy!!!  Create a new static variable at the top of the form called Cancelled.  Then set and read variable to stop the query of the database.

Comment: Actually, you *can* stop the query on the server, through `SqlCommand.Cancel` -- which is one of the few methods that's safe to call from another thread, if you're so inclined. This causes a rather scary looking exception in the consuming code, though, so setting a flag in advance to verify that you did cancel so you can ignore that is a good idea.

Comment: @Fildor: Never used Task, what could be the pros/cons of using it instead of BGW? **jdweng**: Is it the best way to do it? I'm discovering BackgroundWorker, and I'd like to get the cleanest code possible (even if there is some improvement that could be done in the code above, as using Linq for query). **Jeroen**: I'll take a look at `SqlCommand.Cancel`, thank you for this. But I still want to be able to stop the `SqlReader` if the worker is asked to stop after the command already executed successfully.

Comment: See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html. Go through the complete series. It's really worth it.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you, gonna take a look at it.

Comment: GetLignesHS() cannot see that CancellationPending changed.  Pass the BackgroundWorker object or `Func<bool>`.

Comment: What is wrong with `SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken)`
`SqlDataReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken)`
`SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CancellationToken)` ? and `await` instead old ugly `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: @Fildor pretty much effective, gonna use Task from now on. I know that when I started C# a few months ago I learned some bad habits, and now when I try something new I aim to be the cleanest possible and look like Task is way cleaner than BGW. However, I'm still curious about the BGW case. **Hans Passant**: As for jdweng comment upper, is it good practice or conventional to do it this way? **Selvin**: Nothing, just that I wasn't aware that these exist. I'm going to take a look at it, thank you for pointing it to me.